# Pass a SharePoint list item value to a ListViewWebPart query

Tags: 2010, xslt-list-view-web-part, list-view-web-part

I'm stuck with the following Problem:

**The Task:**

I do have a custom SharePoint form which displays an entry from one of my SharePoint lists. On that Form I am using a ListViewWebPart to show the content of a specific Folder from a SharePoint document library.

The query part of that ListViewWebPart looks like this:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Contains>
    <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/>
      <Value Type="Text">{MyParameter}</Value>
    </Contains>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Now if I replace `{MyParameter}` with let's say "Documents/Billing/001" it shows exactly what I want it to show: The content of that folder.

How can I use

**The Problem:**
How can I grab a property of the actual viewed list item (let's say "MyCustomID") and pass it as a parameter to MyParameter in the query of that ListViewWebPart?

**UPDATE**

I am using a simple HTML table containing  entries to display the list item and as described above a ListViewWebPart to display the Document Library

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are both webparts (the list and the details form) on the same page? If so, you can use webpart connections instead of a parameter

Comment: Yes they are both on the same page. But I am displaying the List Item using a HTML Table and then placing <SharePoint:ListItemProperty. Any way to connect them?

Comment: So the page is always displaying the same ListItem?

Comment: No, it shows a selected list item entry.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the ListViewWebPart by code and set the HtmlSchemaView property by reflect.

here is a open-source project : http://camlquery.codeplex.com/
you can find how to set the query condition of ListViewWebPart dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you had a dropdown in your page, where users would select the entry to display? You can bind MyParameter to any ASP control on the page, so your view would be filtered by the dropdown's selection.

You can also populate the dropdown with values from a list item (by binding it to a SPDataSource). Unfortunately a dropdown only has one column to show values.

If this looks like a promising path I will update this post with more info on how to do it.

Comment: sorry, dropdown is not the way we want to go. there must not be any user interaction to show the content of the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make it work but maybe you can use [ListItemProperty](http://msmvps.com/blogs/cobrien/archive/2008/03/16/great-controls-to-be-aware-of-when-building-sharepoint-sites.aspx) control like this:

```
<Where>
                     <Eq>
                         <FieldRef Name="aaa"/>
                         <Value Type='Text'>
                             <ListItemProperty List="{47F75936-D9D1-4B86-900F-F0B111073950}" ListItemID="1" Property="MyCustomID" runat="server">
                             </ListItemProperty>
                         </Value>
                     </Eq>
                 </Where>
```

At least such a construction doesn't break anything.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't make a lot of sense to me